# watchOS: Wrong product name shown when asking for HealthKit authorization

Tags: apple-watch, healthkit, watchos

I created a watchOS standalone app which uses HealthKit. When prompting the user for authorization, the Dialog shows the product name of the app extension (which is "MyApp WatchKit Extension"). I tried replacing `$(PRODUCT_NAME)` in the `Info.plist` file but that didn't change anything. The only thing that worked was changing the Product Name in the build settings. But that's not what I want to do. Any ideas?